# Android 3.2: Receive UDP packets does not work?

Tags: java, android, udp

I am programming an Android tablet app. It communicates via UDP messages (13 bytes data each).
Sending these packets works correctly. But when I try to receive unicast UDP packets on port 15731 (and on other ports as well), it always returns IOException. That's what my code looks like (receiveUDP runs cyclic).

```
public void receiveUDP() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[13];
    try {
        DatagramPacket dataIn = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        DatagramSocket recSocket = new DatagramSocket(15731);
        recSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);
        recSocket.receive(dataIn);
        Log.i("receiveUDP", "UDP Message received: " + buffer.toString());
        recSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("receiveUDP", "IOException");
    }
    ;
}
```

In the Android Manifest I made the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

The e.printfStackTrace() command turns out the following:

```
11-17 14:34:05.130: WARN/System.err(25961): java.net.BindException: Address already in use
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.bind(Native Method)
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.bind(BlockGuard.java:275)
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:77)
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at java.net.DatagramSocket.createSocket(DatagramSocket.java:190)
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:74)
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at com.example.MyService.onCreate(MyService.java:78)
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2103)
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1078)
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-17 14:34:05.140: WARN/System.err(25961):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What does this mean?

Now, if I don't create DatagramSocket and DatagramPacket cyclic any more, I get a different stack trace. It is:

```
11-17 15:06:42.590: WARN/System.err(26812): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-17 15:06:42.590: WARN/System.err(26812):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
11-17 15:06:42.590: WARN/System.err(26812):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.recv(BlockGuard.java:332)
11-17 15:06:42.590: WARN/System.err(26812):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.doRecv(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:165)
11-17 15:06:42.590: WARN/System.err(26812):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:174)
11-17 15:06:42.590: WARN/System.err(26812):     at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:391)
11-17 15:06:42.590: WARN/System.err(26812):     at com.example.MyService.onCreate(MyService.java:114)
11-17 15:06:42.610: WARN/System.err(26812):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2103)
11-17 15:06:42.610: WARN/System.err(26812):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-17 15:06:42.610: WARN/System.err(26812):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1078)
11-17 15:06:42.610: WARN/System.err(26812):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-17 15:06:42.610: WARN/System.err(26812):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-17 15:06:42.610: WARN/System.err(26812):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-17 15:06:42.610: WARN/System.err(26812):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Has anyone an idea why I can't receive UDP packets?

Comment: What's the message and stack trace of the IOException?

Comment: Does e.getMessage() give any insights in the catch?

Comment: I have copied the content of e.printStackTrace in the question. Can you say what it means? I'm pretty new to Java and Android and I have not worked with stack trace til now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things:

Since you reuse the same port, you might need to create a socket, call [setReuseAddress(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setReuseAddress%28boolean%29), and then bind the socket to the port.

[InterruptedIOException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InterruptedIOException.html) is a subclass of IOException, setSOTimeout(1000); will only wait (block) for 1 second before throwing this exception

UPDATED:
The exceptions show the problems:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Which I believe will be fixed by using the setReuseAddress (above)?

and

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Which means you're running this code on a the main UI thread, which will block the responiveness of the UI and possibly cause an ANR (probably not if you keep setSOTimeout(1000), but anyway...). 3.0 and later doesn't allow network requests on the UI thread so you need to put it into an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (or Thread).

Comment: thanks, I increased the timeout to 10 seconds just to make sure. But actually it didn't make it better :(

Comment: hello @FunkTheMonk, I can send/receive data good now. But do u (sender side) often lose connect to firmware side (receiver side) when try to get data from firmware side (receiver side)? Sometimes you can get data correctly, sometimes can not. Do u have any solution?

Comment: That deserves its own question with more details, but if you're having intermittent drop outs, you may need a thread that continuously checks the status of the socket, reinitialising it when required and there is a network connection available (ie, don't bother if you're in aeroplane mode)

Answer (score 0):

You may have networking issues if you are trying this on emulator. Emulator is a virtual machine which is connected directly to your router device. Your emulator cannot reach your local device, or any other devices on the local network.

So that, if you wait answer from your local machine, or another machine on the lan, **you may need portforwarding**.

First try your application on a real device to decide if it is an emulator problem or not, than try other solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i forgot to mention in my question that i'm testing on a real Acer Iconia device.

Answer (score 0):

I used UDP Broadcast on 3.2 once and it worked

Simplified Code of mine:

```
DatagramSocket socket;
socket = new DatagramSocket(aport);
socket.setBroadcast(true);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
socket.receive(packet);
```

This worked for me. If you use broadcasts try setBroadcast(true).

Comment: My problem seems to be somewhere else...The code you posted actually seems to be the code normally used for receiving udp, but in my case there seems to be another error.

Comment: hello @js-, do u (sender side) often lose connect to firmware side (receiver side) when try to get data from firmware side (receiver side)? Sometimes you can get data correctly, sometimes can not. Do u have any solution?